# Сравнение текущего времени с заданным Javascript

Tags: javascript, время

Доброго дня!

Помогите реализовать функцию сравнения текущего времени с заданным в переменной.

Есть такой скрипт с условиями и выводом текста при выполнении условия, но как я понимаю есть определённый формат вывода времени - так как при матиматическом действии над переменными я получаю такой вот вывод...

**Закроемся через:-6970.577217425925**

Условия так же выполняются не верно.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

nowDate = new Date()
openDate = 32400000
closeDate = 64800000

if (nowDate > openDate & nowDate < closeDate) {
    document.write ('Открыто');
}

if (nowDate < openDate & nowDate > closeDate) {
    document.write ('Закрыто');
}

timeToOut = closeDate - nowDate;
document.write ('Закроемся через:' + timeToOut / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 60);

</script>
```

Comment: В переменной `nowDate`  у вас объект типа `Date`. Попробуйте написать `console.log(nowDate)` и сами все увидите. Вместо  `new Date()` сделайте `+(new Date())` или `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: @stepan-kasyanenko
При
   `nowDate = (new Date()).getTime() 
    date = console.log(nowDate)`
Вывод
 `1505710548944`

Вопрос: -это в каких единицах измерения? и как их привести к ЧАС:МИН:СЕК ?

Comment: Если вам надо работать со временем, лучше будет использовать библиотеку [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, для таймстемпа в js правильней использовать `Date.now()`. @TemaKonkin это милисекунды от 1 января 1970. Вам нужно ежедневный график вывести или `openDate` и `closeDate` это даты до одного момента? И в каком они формате?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev `Date.now()` не поддерживается в IE <11 кстати. Когда можно использовать более поддерживаемую альтернативу, которая не менее читабельна и удобна, лучше использовать ее.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, поддерживается в IE 9+. Меньшие ie уже никто почти не поддерживает, но дело вкуса возможно

Comment: @artem-gorlachev по идее - это время работы офиса - с 9:00 до 18:00. Мне нужно высчитать время до закрытия. Допустим если сейчас 17:00 - то вывести "до закрытия осталось: 1 час".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взяв чужой пример за основу и доработав его под свои нужды я сделал то что мне нужно.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTime() {
  var monthsArr = ["Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", 
  "Июля", "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"];

  var daysArr = ["Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"];

  var dateObj = new Date();

  var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
  var month = dateObj.getMonth();
  var numDay = dateObj.getDate();
  var day = dateObj.getDay();
  var hour = dateObj.getHours();
  var minute = dateObj.getMinutes();
  var second = dateObj.getSeconds();

  if (minute < 10) minute = "0" + minute;

  if (second < 10) second = "0" + second;

  openH = 09;
  openM = 00;
  openS = 00;

  closeH = 18;
  closeM = 00;
  closeS = 00;



  if ((openH < hour) && (openM < minute) && (openS < second)) document.write ('<br> Сечас открыто');
  if ((openH > hour) && (openM > minute) && (openS > second)) document.write ('<br> <p style="color: #ff0707;">Сейчас закрыто</p>');


  toCloseH = closeH - hour -1;
  toCloseM = 60 - minute;
  toCloseS = 60 - second;

  document.write ('<br>До закрытия: ' + toCloseH + "ч " + toCloseM + "м");

  var out = daysArr[day] + ", " + numDay + " " + monthsArr[month] + " " + year + ", " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

 return ".";
}

document.write (showTime());
</script>
```

Comment: В разы меньше и проще код получится, если считать в секундах, тк сравнивать надо только один параметр, а не 7